# Why can I store an array of one type in a variable of another type?

Tags: java, arrays, generics

```
Object[] arr1 = new String[]{"0"};
CharSequence[] arr2 = new String[]{"0"};
arr1[0] = 0; // compiles; causes exception at runtime
```

With generics, you cannot:

```
// java.util.ArrayList<CharSequence> list1 = new java.util.ArrayList<String>(); won't compile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Generics and Arrays : not the same rules.**

Generic collections are not reifiable while arrays are. 
It means that at runtime, a compiled `List<String>` is considered by the JVM as a `List` instance while a compiled `String[]` is considered by the JVM as an array of `String` instance.

At compile time, the compiler allows to assign an array of a type to a array variable declared with the super type of it.
It allows it because the check of the validity of the elements stored in the array could be performed at runtime :

```
Number[] numberArray = {1, 5F};
Integer[] integerArray = {1};
numberArray = integerArray; // compile fine
numberArray[0] = 5;  // fine at runtime as valid type
numberArray[0] = 5F; // exception at runtime as Integer[] should not store Float.
```

But because of erasure, it is not possible to do the same check at runtime with generics.

So, the JLS is more restrictive for generics at compile time.
Consequently, `Arrays` are covariant while generics collections are invariant.

Answer (score 2):

The theory was that, because `String` is a child class of `Object`, it could be extended so that `String[]` could be a child class `Object[]`.

By the time Java 5 came around and generics were being designed, they had discovered that this was a bad idea, and worked to prevent it in generics.

Answer (score 0):

Every class in Java is a child of the `Object` class. Since `arr1` is an array of `Object` items, it can take in anything, both strings and ints.